# Attaching wall frame and soffit to a load supporting beam

Tags: framing

The image shows a load supporting beam in a basement. The plan is to attach a wall frame (depicted by green colored lines) and a soffit (red colored lines) to the load supporting beam. A very basic question: Is it OK to fasten these structures to the existing supporting beam? Can the fasteners (3 inch screws) (1) damage the supporting beam or (2) can the supporting beam cause problems down the road to the new wall and soffit by thermal expansion movement?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is ok to add your wall and box in the vent lines. This is is very common, in fact.

Comment: I agree on both counts. Walls under beams like this are indeed very common, and they're usually fastened to the beam with pneumatic framing nails. I'm not sure how one would practically demonstrate that these are facts, but they are.