# Framing lally column inside partition wall

Tags: basement, framing, partition

I'm finishing a room in my basement and want to frame a partition wall underneath the support beam. I've looked at the threads below to confirm that it is OK to frame a partition wall underneath the beam. There's a 3.5" lally column that's 7' away from the concrete wall and I want it inside the partition wall rather than at the corner. The beam is 5.75" thick, the lally column is ~3/4" from the edge of the beam. The beam is not vertically level. Either the finished inside wall will be flush with the beam, or the studs will be flush with the beam (and I'll attach drywall to the studs & the beam), or the beam will just be protruding inside the room.  What do you suggest? I'm prioritizing functionality over aesthetics.

Added image to illustrate gap between drywall & beam (after stud is flush with the beam). This is an exaggeration - the beam isn't vertically straight when I place a level against it.

[How do I drywall a corner with a lally column?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/81265/how-do-i-drywall-a-corner-with-a-lally-column)

[Attaching wall frame and soffit to a load supporting beam](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/185012/attaching-wall-frame-and-soffit-to-a-load-supporting-beam)

[image: Floor plan showing new partition walls]

[image: Lally Column]

[image: Lally Column Close-up]

[image: Illustration of gap between drywall and beam]

Comment: The only function of the wall will be to hold drywall.  About the only thing to decide is what will look better finish.  2x4 studs will leave the beam sticking out.  2x6 or 2x4 plus 2x2s should hide everything behind drywall.

Comment: 2x4s flush to the right. That leaves you the beam as a runner for the soffit that needs to be on the left anyway for the duct.

Comment: @crip659, good idea using 2x6 instead of 2x4. If I frame the studs flush with the beam, there will be slight gaps between the beam and the drywall (the beam has a slight incline). Would I use shims to ensure the drywall is vertically level from floor to ceiling?

Comment: @Mazura, good point. I was only thinking about the room and not considering additional basement work in the future. So with the 2x4, the lally column will be sticking out but I'll have a runner for a soffit in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's a partition wall - not load-bearing, just dividing space.

So, functionally, the less space it takes up, the better. You did say you were prioritizing function. The only thing more functionally efficient than a really thin wall is a set of built-in shelving serving as a partition where the "thickness" of the wall is mostly shelf space, and the space lost is only the back of the shelves and whatever space goes in boxing around the column and the verticals of the shelves. If, of course, you have things that need shelf space. Empty shelf space you'll never use is not efficient.

2x4 at the most, possibly even 2x3 with extra attention paid to protecting cables in the wall, or else run the electrical for the required outlets on the surface, or wires in conduit whether in the wall or on the surface. 2x4 makes passing the column easy with the drywall, 2x3 involves tapering (not  the same as taping, not a typo) and mudding as the drywall goes by the column as the column will stick out beyond the 2x3s.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Ecnerwal. I added an image to show that the beam is not vertically straight. Would I place shims between the drywall and the beam or does that matter?